# Display json array from given url

Tags: jquery, json

im new to JSON and i would like to ask a question after couple of days of searching without any good result.
i have a URL which contain a JSON array, i would like to know how to display it to a table with prepered keys. e.g: username , password , email is the first table row and now only need to fill the data.
im would like to use only jQuery for that due to the lack of knowlage in ajax.

Comment: *"i have a URL which contain a JSON array"*: The JSON data is part of the query or how exactly is it contained? Please provide an example. You are asking a quite high level question, whereas Stackoverflow is better suited for concrete technical questions.

Comment: with this url in Post ill receive a JSON array of users. for example $.getJSON("currentrl", function(data){ }); only problem, it is not working for me..

Comment: Ah, so you are making a request *to* a URL and receive JSON from it. The data is not contained *in* the URL. Please post your code and explain exactly *what* "is not working". What do you expect to happen and what happens? Do you get any errors? What did you found out through [debugging your code](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners)?

Comment: $.getJSON("http://37.19.113.5/Test/Home/GetUsers", function(data){
  alert(data);
 });

its not even alerting something....

Comment: It looks like you are doing a cross-domain request. You cannot do cross-domain requests with Ajax unless the server supports it. (please [**edit** your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15810900/edit) and add your code).

Comment: it is supporting it. u can even try and see it works for you as well..

Comment: For the server to support it, CORS has to be enabled (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Are you sure it is? Have a look at the response headers (it should list `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` or something similar) and let me know. When I open the URL in my browser I get a 404 response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't get an alert here, the request failed. This is why there is a .fail() method:

```
$.getJSON( "test.js", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } )
.done(function( json ) {
    console.log( "JSON Data: " + json.users[3].name );
})
.fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
    var err = textStatus + ', ' + error;
    console.log( "Request Failed: " + err);
});
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

When you want to retrieve JSON data from POST, you cannot use [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

> Load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request.

[Try this instead](http://jsfiddle.net/avfRT/1/):

```
$.post( "justaurl")
.done(function( data ) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    alert( json.Users[3].FirstName );
})
.fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
    var err = textStatus + ', ' + error;
    alert( "Request Failed: " + err);
});
```

Comment: im not using any debugger, so if i change console.log to alert, will it work the same ? @jgillich

p.s
i would like to get the answer using my url please

Comment: Sure, both console and alert do the same (display a string). Bout I would recommend using a debugger where you can print objects. Chrome has one built in, for Firefox you can use Firebug. Here is the code with your link and alert: http://jsfiddle.net/avfRT/

Comment: is says "Error, Not found" @jgillich

Comment: @VeraGavriel That's because the server behind the URL returns a `404` error (Not found) and not a JSON object.

Comment: it suppose to return JSON array in POST

Comment: added alert("after post"); after the $.post.... and not even alerting me then..probably cant red the $.post method

Comment: im only using those scripts, maybe that could be the problem..
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js"></script>

Comment: @VeraGavriel Can you create a new fiddle with what you've tried? And really, use a javascript debugger, otherwise you won't even get syntax errors displayed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qSfs7/1/   ur function kinda making my table not showing his other css file probably due to the fact it cant read the $.post

Comment: i think that the problem is the documentation.. i only got to jquery and json2 ... maybe i need another docu? @jgillich

Comment: it helped, only need to delete the parser